# Presented UIImagePickerController camera could take photo or cancel

Tags: xcode, ios7, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UIImagePickerController which opens a camera, as the sample code bellow shows.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker
                   animated:YES
                 completion:NULL];
```

My Problem: When I present the camera, the camera shows, but I could not take a picture nor tap to cancel. Even the flip camera icon does not respond.
Happening on iOS versions below 8, iPad.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and its working on iPad 2 iOs7.1.2
you might try using setters, this is how i am doing it

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [picker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet]; 
}
else
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```